# How to refactor case..when in Ruby

Tags: ruby, refactoring, rubocop, reek

```
  def readable
    uptime = (Time.now - self).to_i
    case uptime
    when 0 then 'just now'
    when 1 then 'uptime second ago'
    when 2..59 then uptime.to_s + ' seconds ago'
    when 60..119 then 'uptime minute ago' # 120 = 2 minutes
    when 120..3540 then (uptime / 60).to_i.to_s + ' minutes ago'
    when 3541..7100 then 'an hour ago' # 3600 = 1 hour
    when 7101..82_800 then ((uptime + 99) / 3600).to_i.to_s + ' hours ago'
    when 82_801..172_000 then 'uptime day ago' # 86400 = 1 day
    else ((uptime + 800) / 86_400).to_i.to_s + ' days ago'
    end
  end
```

Linter speaks of the following mistakes, how can this be fixed?

- FeatureEnvy: Time#readable refers to 'uptime' more than self (maybe move it to another class?) [https://github.com/troessner/reek/blob/master/docs/Feature-Envy.md]
- TooManyStatements: Time#readable has approx 10 statements [https://github.com/troessner/reek/blob/master/docs/Too-Many-Statements.md]
- Assignment Branch Condition size for readable is too
  high. [20.64/15]
- Cyclomatic complexity for readable is too high. [9/6]
- Method has too many lines. [12/10]

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the proper place for this kind of question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is working code, and should instead be posted on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: This is a case where I temporarily disable the rubocop rules b/c I agree it's a pretty concise implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [time_ago_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words) and feel free to use it or its code.

About code metrics - your code is pretty simple, you should extract only `uptime` method.

Comment: The [implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.1.4/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L93-L156) is not that much simpler, is it?

Comment: Of course. There is no chances to write it simpler. I was referred to it just thinking about Don't repeat Rails :)